# Since when are away missions filmed?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the *TNG* Season 4 episode **"Identity Crisis"**, La Forge is in a race against time to figure out why he and some former crew mates from the USS Victory are changing into

> weird blue glow-in-the dark chameleon-like creatures.

The suspicion is that they came into contact with something on the planet Tarchannen III some years prior during an away mission.  La Forge conveniently spends a lot of time studying footage from the away mission, which was taken by one of the other officers using a GoPro-style head mounted camera:

[image]

The needs of plot aside...

## Have we seen this before?  At what point did it become (or cease to become) standard procedure to *film* away missions?

Does it have to do with the nature of the mission (which was to investigate the mysterious disappearance of individuals stationed on the planet)?  What is the general protocol regarding visual records of away missions?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180097/why-there-has-been-no-mobile-visual-transmission-device-remote-camera-to-the-br

Comment: @Praxis There seem to be many different questions here (the protocol of away missions, that specific mission, the video recording by La Forge etc). Perhaps you could make it a bit more specific?

Comment: @Loki : They are really all the same / one question.

Comment: The graphic does say "sensor log", maybe it's just so routine that it's never been noticed before.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt : In Geordi's holodeck recreation of the scene, we definitely see one of the crewmen filming it all with a head-mounted camera.  So unless every other away mission has had someone wearing a head cam and we haven't noticed it, this definitely isn't routine.

Comment: Every episode you've ever watched is being recorded by a redshirt with a headcam. Geordi was just watching an episode from the voyages of the USS Victory. They must be on Netflix, somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

```
Have we seen this before?  Here are a few somewhat similar examples:
```

In *Heart of Glory*, they live stream Geordi's visor to the bridge view screen, so the bridge can view what the away team are seeing.

In *Time Squared*, Geordi is able to retrieve and replay video logs of a shuttle.